# Loaded event not firing in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

In the following code, person.Children contains 3 other Person objects. This code adds the child.Loaded event handler to all three, but child_Loaded only executes for the first two. Any idea why this is?

```
foreach ( Person child in person.Children)
        {
            //Add children in same position as parent
            child.x_PositionTransform.X = person.x_PositionTransform.X;
            child.x_PositionTransform.Y = person.x_PositionTransform.Y;

            child.SetValue(Canvas.NameProperty, "child" + objCount++);
            child.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(person_Click);
            x_LayoutRoot.Children.Add(child);

            child.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(child_Loaded);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure that this is the issue, but I'd try setting the `Loaded` event handler before adding the child to the `x_LayoutRoot` object.